# How to read a chunk of lines that match a starting pattern from a file in Python?

Tags: python

From a data file that contains HTTP response and HTML page content, I want to extract HTTP response (and header) only using Python.

The data file has the following repeated pattern, the response and headers are always separated from the content with an empty line, and it always start with HTTP/1.1. What I want is to extract text from the line `HTTP/1.1 200 OK' to the line above the empty line (the text in bold font).

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

**Server: nginx**

**Date: Thu, 23 May 2019 19:49:06 GMT**

**Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8**

**X-Crawler-Transfer-Encoding: chunked**

[empty line]

Page content ...

[empty line]

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

**...**

This is what I have so far, don't know how to proceed. I am not familiar with Python, can't figure out how to read a few lines and skip them in the loop.

```py
with open('data') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        firstWord = line.split(' ')[0]
        if firstWord == 'HTTP/1.1':
                  what to do next?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a flag (e.g. `read`) to check if you want to read or not:

```
responses=[]
resp=''
read=False
with open('data') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        firstWord = line.split(' ')[0]
        if firstWord == 'HTTP/1.1':
            resp=line
            read=True
        elif firstWord=='\n' and resp:
            responses.append(resp)
            resp=''
            read=False
        elif read:
            resp+=line
print(responses)
```

Comment: This get the job done, thank you! But is there a nicer way to do this? Say if I have explicit loop such as (i=0; i < lines.len; i++), if firstWord matches, I can simply do (i++) to let the loop jump over this certain line, can I do this in Python type of loop?

Comment: Np, make sure to mark it answered if it answered your question. And yes, just add another if statement that checks for that firstWord (e.g. you could change `elif read` to `elif read and firstWord!='skipword'`)